# Codeigniter Pagination using ID and Distinct Name

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have got codeigniter pagination working perfectly, what I want it to do now is to navigate using the next & previous buttons according to the ID of the product and keeping it ordered by name in alphabetical order. Also to only display one product at a time.

The one thing I must note, that is if 2 or more products share the same name, they are then grouped together to form one product with various attributes. So I would need it to paginate according to product ID while keeping the results DISTINCT to the name of the product.

I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

The pagination is for a incremental sequence, e.g. 1,2,3,4. Unless I've misread you probably won't be able to do this. You could create use the numbers as an index, e.g. 4 links to the 4th product in your query list.

You will need to create a SQL queries for the pages, generate the urls and html list (ul) manually. Probably array_slice depending on how many products you have. If you have a really large database you will have to be quite clever in using MySQL's LIMIT argument.

```
 SELECT id, name FROM `table` ORDER BY `name` ASC GROUP BY `name`
```

Then loop through to create the unordered list. If you are doing this on multiple controllers and views you may want to use the man functions in a model.